# Multivariate Generalized Least Squares

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, multivariate-analysis, model, generalized-least-squares

I'd like to use the generalized least squares (GLS) in the multivariate version. I have a response variable $\boldsymbol{Y}$ with dimension $n \times m$, where $n$ indicates the number of observations and $m$ indicates the number of components of the random vector $\boldsymbol{Y}$. Besides, I have the regressors variables with dimension $n \times p$, where $p$ indicates the number of regressors.

How is the multivariate case for the GLS? I have read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_linear_model, but this version is for the univariate case, that is, $\boldsymbol{Y}$ has dimension $n \times 1$. Any reference or hints are welcome.

Comment: Are you looking for software implementation of theoretical discussion ob this topic?

Comment: I need a book, paper or R package.